# Is the linear probability model (LPM) less inappropriate when the independent variable of interest is binary? (and controls are continuous)

Tags: regression, categorical-data, binary-data

I need to use an LPM for a paper I'm doing (for reasons orthogonal to this question). I have about 6000 observations in a time series cross-sectional structure (countries and years) and my dependent variable is binary.

Now, I know all the standard arguments against the LPM, but I am wondering whether the case for using it is better when the independent variable of interest is binary? As far as I can tell, if all independent variables are binary the LPM is completely general, but I have some controls that are continuous.

So, is the LPM equally bad if the independent variable of interest is binary?

Comment: How does a distinction between "independent variable" and "controls" arise here and how it can be pertinent to the merits of LPMs? More directly, are you confusing "independent" and "dependent" variables? (Such confusion, incidentally, is common in my experience and one of several reasons to abandon that common but over-used terminology.)

Comment: Calling a predictor a "control" doesn't change anything about the model, & note that the estimated coefficient for the predictor of interest will depend on how you model the control variables; so the LPM is as bad or good in this case as in one where you're interested in all predictors.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies!  @NickCox Sorry, I'll try to clear up the terminology: I have a binary dependent/outcome/response variable (hence the LPM) and a mix of continuous and binary independent/explanatory/predictor variables of which I'm interested in the coefficient on one. And that one variable is binary. @ Scortchi Yeah, the coefficient I'm interested in will of course depend on the modelling of the others. Makes sense. So I guess the answer to my question must be "yes".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. On the contrary, my guess is more like "no": the virtues of the LPM are no greater, and no less, depending on what predictors you use, as discussion centres on whether the response is being treated in the right way.

Comment: I should perhaps say that I got the idea from reading the chapter on discrete response models in Wooldridge's "econometric analysis of cross section and panel data". Here he states that the case for the LPM becomes stronger with many discrete independent/explanatory/predictor variables (p. 456 ch. 15 in my 2001 version).

Comment: @NickCox Yeah, I agree. Was responding "yes" to whether the LPM was equally bad/good when the independent variable of interest was binary. I should probably be clearer when I write stuff : )

Comment: Your title question and closing question do indeed have similar content but quite different wording.

Comment: They do indeed. Anyway, thanks a lot for the response - it's a great help to my project!